# How to fix mbeans javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: spring, log4j2, war

We are deploying vendor provided WAR files inside Wildlfly an we get the below error.  This error is occurring only when the second war file is getting deployed.

We understand that there is duplicate.  How can we identify the duplicate and fix.  Thanks.

```
{"timestamp":"2023-11-24T17:15:52.757Z","sequence":279,"loggerClassName":"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.JBossLog","loggerName":"org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler","level":"INFO","message":"Spring Security 'config' module version is 5.7.2","threadName":"ServerService Thread Pool -- 136","threadId":222,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"transact-temenos-transact-api-6d956df74-kxzj8","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":204,"label":"value"}
{"timestamp":"2023-11-24T17:15:52.828Z","sequence":280,"loggerClassName":"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.JBossLog","loggerName":"org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser","level":"INFO","message":"Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <jwtTokenValidationFilter>, order = 2701, Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder$SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterBeanFactory#0; factoryMethodName=getBean; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 3600, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 3700]","threadName":"ServerService Thread Pool -- 136","threadId":222,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"transact-temenos-transact-api-6d956df74-kxzj8","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":204,"label":"value"}
2023-11-24 17:15:53,866 ServerService Thread Pool -- 136 ERROR Could not register mbeans javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=a852d73
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:1517)
        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:400)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:168)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:632)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.wrapper.log4j2.LoggerFactoryLog4j2.getLogger(LoggerFactoryLog4j2.java:37)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.wrapper.log4j2.Log4jLoggerEngine.getLogger(Log4jLoggerEngine.java:127)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.facade.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:140)
        at com.temenos.logger.AbstractLogger.<init>(AbstractLogger.java:41)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.Diagnostic.<init>(Diagnostic.java:33)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.getLogger(DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.java:36)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.forModule(DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.java:26)
        at com.temenos.irf.logging.IrisTemenosLogImpl.debug(IrisTemenosLogImpl.java:65)
        at com.temenos.irf.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:23)
        at com.temenos.irf.core.SlaMappingsReader.readSlaMappingsFromFile(SlaMappingsReader.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

2023-11-24 17:15:53,866 ServerService Thread Pool -- 136 ERROR Could not register mbeans javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=a852d73
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:1517)
        at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.register(Server.java:400)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:168)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:632)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.wrapper.log4j2.LoggerFactoryLog4j2.getLogger(LoggerFactoryLog4j2.java:37)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.wrapper.log4j2.Log4jLoggerEngine.getLogger(Log4jLoggerEngine.java:127)
        at com.temenos.logger.logging.facade.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:140)
        at com.temenos.logger.AbstractLogger.<init>(AbstractLogger.java:41)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.Diagnostic.<init>(Diagnostic.java:33)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.getLogger(DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.java:36)
        at com.temenos.logger.diagnostics.DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.forModule(DiagnosticsLoggerFactory.java:26)
        at com.temenos.irf.logging.IrisTemenosLogImpl.debug(IrisTemenosLogImpl.java:65)
        at com.temenos.irf.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:23)
        at com.temenos.irf.core.SlaMappingsReader.readSlaMappingsFromFile(SlaMappingsReader.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

Answer (score 0):

JMX support is actually an optional feature of Log4j Core, which is turned on by default (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/jmx.html)). You can disable it by setting the system property `log4j2.disableJmx` to `true`.

The error message is due to **two** different copies of `log4j-api` trying to register two different `LoggerContext`s under the same JMX name. This should normally not happen, since the JMX name of the logger context (`a852d73` in your case) is based on the classloader associated with it.

So either both web applications use the same classloader (which is unusual) or both classloaders have the same `hashCode`.